# Issue creating Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm facing issue while creating a stored procedure in SQL Server; is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?

I have added the query to create the database and create the procedure, thanks a lot for your help and guidance.

Please do let me know if you need more details!

Stored procedure (troublesome)

```
USE [ChartSample]  
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SC_GetPlayers]  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SELECT  *  
    FROM CS_Player   
END  

USE [ChartSample]  
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId] 
    @PlayerId INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SELECT  
        PlayerId, 
        Year,  
        TotalRun, TotalWickets,  
        ODIMatches, TestMatches  
    FROM    
        CS_PlayerRecord  
    WHERE   
        PlayerId = @PlayerId  
END
```

Error message:

> Msg 154, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SC_GetPlayers, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   A USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 21]
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId'.

Query to create small database:

```
CREATE DATABASE ChartSample  

USE [ChartSample]  
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  
SET ANSI_PADDING ON  
GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CS_Player]
(  
    [PlayerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [PlayerName] [varchar](50) NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CS_Player] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PlayerId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO  

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF  
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CS_PlayerRecord]
(  
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [PlayerId] [int] NULL,  
    [Year] [int] NULL,  
    [TotalRun] [int] NULL,  
    [TotalWickets] [int] NULL,  
    [ODIMatches] [int] NULL,  
    [TestMatches] [int] NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CS_PlayerRecord] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CS_layerRecord]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CS_PlayerRecord_CS_Player] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PlayerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CS_Player]([PlayerId])  
GO  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CS_PlayerRecord] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CS_PlayerRecord_CS_Player]  
GO
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? What are you asking?

Comment: Hi, thnaks for your response, I'm getting  this error  (error added to question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `GO` between two procs else it will considered as part of `SC_GetPlayers` proc code. Using `GO` will help the compiler to understand it is the end of batch

Edit : seems like you are trying to create procs, so use `Create` instead `Alter`

```
Create PROC [dbo].[SC_GetPlayers]  
AS  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT  *  
        FROM    CS_Player   
    END  

GO--here

USE [ChartSample]  
GO  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  
Create PROC [dbo].[SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId] @PlayerId INT  
..
```

Comment: sorry that didnt help, im still getting the same error

Comment: here, Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SC_GetPlayers, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 7]
Invalid object name 'dbo.SC_GetPlayers'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 22]
Invalid object name 'dbo.SC_GetPlayerRecordsBtPlayerId'.

Comment: @zufuzoje - you need to use `create` instead of `alter`.. check the updated query

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GO` before your 2nd `USE` statement.

Also just as side note, appears you might have wanted to spell your 2nd stored procedure: 
`GetPlayerRecordsByPlayerID`

Comment: sorry that didnt help, im still getting the same error